# Rails3 update existing record, create new simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Quote model has a number of variables.  A quote can be added to a Cart, as a LineItem.
Quote has_many :line_items,

```
LineItem 
  belongs_to :quote
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote
```

The idea is that if a Quote is added to the cart, its status changes (:final => true)
quote_controller in its show action instantiates

```
 @line_item = LineItem.new
```

The Quote's show view includes a form which needs to do two things simultaneously:

1. create the line_item.  This is generated by `<%= f.hidden_field :quote, :value => @quote.id %>`
2. update the quote.

The second element is the issue

```
<%= form_for(@line_item) do |f| %>
 [...]
  <%= fields_for @line_item.quote do |quote_fields| %>
    <%= quote_fields.hidden_field :final, :value => true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This returns the error `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`.  Odd though, the context is already that model.

Comment: try changing `<%= fields_for @line_item.quote do |quote_fields| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :quote do |quote_fields| %>`

Comment: Right, I see. I'l try that to the side, but the solution is not syntax related: simplifying conceptually was required.

Comment: it's not syntax. when `@line_item.quote` returns `nil`, that's most probably the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The question was a garden path.  The mistake is

```
A quote can be added to a Cart, as a LineItem.
```

No need for the LineItem.  Quote can belong to a Cart.  The assignment of cart_id does the trick.
  Then the show view includes a form to edit that same record

```
    <%= form_for(@quote) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :cart_id, :value => @cart.id %>
```

The cart then contains all its quotes and whatever it needs.